# Reverting after installing lubuntu desktop

Tags: 12.04, lts

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS and then found the Lubuntu desktop in Ubuntu Software Center.

If I install it, would I later be able to revert to the ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, every time you log in you would be able to choose which desktop environment you want to use.

In the top right corner of the log in field (Ubuntu Login) there is a small logo. Just click on it and click on the desktop environment you wish to log into...